# Declare a private static nested class with a public constructor Java?

Tags: java, inner-classes, static-classes

How do I create an instance of a static private inner class with a public constructor?

```
public class outerClass<E> {
private static class innerClass<E> {
    E value;
    
    public innerClass(E e) {
        value = e;
    }
}}
```

I've tried this and it gives an error that the out package does not exist

```
outerClass<Integer> out = new outerClass<Integer>();
out.innerClass<Integer> = new out.innerClass<Integer>(1);
```

I've tried this and it gives an error that the inner class is private and can't be accessed.

```
outerClass<Integer>.innerClass<Integer> = new 
outerClass<Integer>.innerClass<Integer>(1)
```

Comment: `new innerClass<...>(...)`  from inside `outerClass`. From outside `outerClass` it's inaccessible because you declared it private.

Comment: `static` means it behaves as as if it were declared at top level (i.e. does not hold a reference to the syntactically enclosing class. `private` means it cannot be seen outside its enclosing class, so there's no point in `new outerClass.innerClass` because where the name `innerClass` is in scope it won't need to be qualified.

Comment: So essentially, I cannot declare inner class unless I am writing code from inside outerclass?

Any code I write from a separate program that calls this will be unable to instantiate the inner class because it is private?

Comment: That's what private means: only accessible inside the containing class.

Answer (score 0):

> `new out.innerClass<Integer>(1);`

But this doesn't make sense. `innerClass` is declared `static`, which means that innerClass has nothing to do with `outerClass`; it is merely located within it for namespacing purposes (and, perhaps, that outer and inner can access `private` members), but that is where it ends. So, `out`, being an **instance** of `outerClass`, has no business being there.

> `new  outerClass<Integer>.innerClass<Integer>(1)`

That also doesn't make any sense - outerClass is being mentioned here just for the purposes of namespacing: To tell java what class you mean. Thus, the `<Integer>` on that makes no sense.

### how do I do it then?

```
new outerClass.innerClass<Integer>(1);
```

Comment: It's saying innerClass has private access in outerClass, and won't let me compile

Comment: Yes, your class is private. Only code within the `outerClass.java` file can call it. That's... what `private` means. That's like going: "Okay, I have made a circle shape, but, now... how do I put corners on this thing?".

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention an constraints, so....

### Reflection to the rescue!

```java
package com.example;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class ReflectionTest {

    public static class OuterClass<E> {
        private static class InnerClass<E> {
            E value;

            public InnerClass(E e) {
                value = e;
            }
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void should_instantiate_private_static_inner_class_w_reflection()
            throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, NoSuchFieldException,
                   IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {

        Class<?> innerCls = Class.forName("com.example.ReflectionTest$OuterClass$InnerClass");
        Constructor<?> ctor = innerCls.getConstructor(Object.class);

        Object instance = ctor.newInstance(10);
        Field valueField = innerCls.getDeclaredField("value");
        valueField.setAccessible(true);
        Object value = valueField.get(instance);

        assertEquals(value, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: @thatotherguy Except that it won’t work in Java 9 and later when modules are in use.